Graphing different time series data in python
I have two different time series of data as shown below.

I want to put these two different sets of time series values on a graph. The code is as follows, unfortunately, it is not the effect I want.The second picture is how I want it to look
plt.figure
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df['TIME1'][1:100],df['DATA1'][1:100])
ax.plot(df['TIME2'][1:100],df['DATA2'][1:100])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(ticker_spacing1))
plt.show()



I would like to ask how to plot these two sets of data on a graph in chronological order, thanks in advance for your reply!

What is df[['TIME1', 'TIME2']].dtypes?

I assume df["TIME2"] is not sorted? It appears there is one specific point that is out of order.

Actually, it is in chronological order, but I don't know why the drawing looks like this.

it is timedelta
